# Get Proper XPath for SelectNodes

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I just started using HtmlAgilityPack to scrape some text from websites. I have experimented and found that some websites are easier than others in regards to getting the proper XPath when using the `SelectNodes` method. I believe I am doing something wrong but can't figure it out.

For example when exploring the DOM in Google Chrome, I am able to copy the XPath: `//*[@id="page"]/span/table[7]/tbody/tr[1]/td/span[2]/a` then I would do something like..

`var search = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id=\"page\"]//span//table//tr//td//span//a"` 
When using the `search` in a `foreach loop` I get a null reference error and sure enough the debugger says `search` is null. So I am assuming the XPath is wrong..(or I am doing something else totally wrong) So my question is how exactly do I get the proper XPath for HtmlAgilityPack to find these nodes?

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out.. The xpath was contained in an iframe.

Comment: Be aware that you can use extensions that support css selectors, such as `ScrapySharp`, along with `HtmlAgilityPack`, and you will be able to use css instead of xpath, if that makes it easier for you (for me it does, since I am already familiar with css but not with xpath). In addition, `AngleSharp` is a parser like `HtmlAgilityPack` but provides built in support for css selectors, with no need for other packages.

Comment: @Veverke I will check out your suggestions. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Veverke would you happen to know a library that would be able to scrape data off an iFrame on the current page? I've tested ScrapySharp and it is much easier (Thanks again) however just like HtmlAgilityPack, it does not work on direct iframe source on the page. It would only work if I scrape the iframe source url itself.

Comment: What is the site you are trying to parse ? I can take a look. However, if the iframe is loaded by javascript or loaded dynamically in the html - it will not indeed be available at request response time and thus parsing alone will not help. AngleSharp - I thought was able to process javascript before rendering the final html document - but I was not able to have it working for me yet.

Comment: @Veverke how about this link http://financials.morningstar.com/company-profile/c.action?t=AAPL&amp;region=usa&amp;culture=en-US .. I'm trying to get the email. But it looks like the site has some fancy js or iframe that is not allowing me to scrape anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on what you request in your last comment, the html is fully rendered only after the http get request is returns.

Several javascript calls insert blocks of html into the document.

You want the following of them: `loadCompanyProfileData('ContactInfo')`, which generates an http get request that looks like:

`http://financials.morningstar.com/cmpind/company-profile/component.action?component=ContactInfo&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&_=1465809033745`.

This returns the email, which you can extract with code like the following:
            HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = w.Load("http://financials.morningstar.com/cmpind/company-profile/component.action?component=ContactInfo&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&_=1465809033745");

```
        var emails = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("a")
            .Where(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href")
                .StartsWith("mailto:"))
                .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href")
                    .Replace("mailto:", string.Empty));
```

emails ends up containing 1 element, being investor_relations@apple.com.

You problem is to determine what should be the "cur" parameter that the loadCompanyProfileData javascript function uses for each distinct company.

I could not locate in the code where/how is this parameter generated.
One alternative would be to execute a browser emulator (like [selenium web driver port for c#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver)) so you can execute javascript code - and run the call to `loadCompanyProfileData('ContactInfo')` for each company request.

But I could not get this to work as well, my web drive script execution does not look to be working.

Comment: Thank for the taking the time to interpret this for me!

Comment: Many others did the same for me here, am just (trying) to give back ;)

Comment: how were you able to get the link provided in your answer? I need to get other stuff as well but would like to try to figure it out myself. Did you get it by inspecting the element source in Chrome or Firefox? I was able to get "financials.morningstar.com/cmpind/company-profile/component.action?component="+component+"&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur="

Comment: Mouse right-click on the page, anywhere, then select View Source Code.